# Finding last occurences of element in Array of Array with lastIndexOf

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is it possible somehow to use the `lastIndexOf` method to get the value of a variable in an array of array? For example if I had

`[[1,2,3,4],[4,6,4,7,5], [5,7,4,6,3], [6,2,5,4,3]]`

and I wanted to find the index of the last array where `[1]` was 2? In the above I would expect the answer to be 3 as the third array has `[1]` equal to 2.

I can see how I can make this work with nested loops or array methods but just wondered if there's some syntax I'm not aware of. Cheers

Comment: No, there's no such thing as `.findLastIndex()` that would accept a function so you can test the elements against an arbitrary set of rules. You can only do this [by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929260/find-last-index-of-element-inside-array-by-certain-condition).

Comment: `for` loop from the end `for(let i = arr.length -1; i >= 0; i--) `  and `break` when a match is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Because [`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) only accepts an element, and not a callback, you can't use `lastIndexOf()` for this case directly.

Given this, and that there's no standard `findLastIndex()` prototype function, you'll have to write this functionality yourself. Here's one such way, using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), while avoiding mutating the original array:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3,4],[4,6,4,7,5], [5,7,4,6,3], [6,2,5,4,3]];

function findLastIndex(arr, callback) {
  return (arr.length - 1) - // Need to subtract found, backwards index from length
    arr.slice().reverse() // Get reversed copy of array
    .findIndex(callback); // Find element satisfying callback in rev. array
}

console.log(findLastIndex(arr, (e) => e[1] == 2));
```

<sub>I discovered `arr.slice().reverse()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929530/11047824) by user [@Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh), which is [*much* faster](https://perf.link/#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%3D) than my previous reducer.</sub>

Comment: Ah. And just as I got my head around spread :-) Out of interest would it not be quicker to reverse the array outside of the function so it only happens once?

Comment: You're welcome to do that, but If I was searching an array, even backwards, I'd expect the original array not to be modified by the function, which is why I took this approach :)