# Get the last capitalized letter from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to get the last uppercase letter from the string and wondering how can I do it. I want to write a function that takes the string and returns the last uppercase letter from that string.

For example, If I call the function with word 'LonDon', I should get D. And if I call the function with word 'CaliforNia', I get N.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last index of element inside array by certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929260/find-last-index-of-element-inside-array-by-certain-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression, probably `[A-Z](?=[^A-Z]*$)`

- [A-Z]: match any capital letter
- (?=[^A-Z]*$): Followed by any # of non-uppercase and the end of the string.

```js
let regex = /[A-Z](?=[^A-Z]*$)/;

console.log({
 CaliforNia: 'CaliforNia'.match(regex)[0],
 LonDon: 'LonDon'.match(regex)[0]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function findLastCap(text) {
  let length = text.length - 1;
  for (let i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (text[i] !== text[i].toLowerCase()) return text[i];
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(findLastCap("aaaaaaBccc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know javascript but I can help you come up with an algorithm that would solve this problem.

First I will write it in python3 and explain what I did and you can try to translate it into javascript.

```
def last_upper(string):
    last = "" # i make a string var here
    
    for let in string:
        
        if let.issupper():
           last = let
    return last
```

So basically what I did in this code is that I iterate through all the elements in the string and if a letter is uppercase it will update the last variable. It works because it keeps on updating it each time it finds a uppercase letter.

Comment: Great! Thanks Matt, I did try with using temp variable similar to your solution so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let reg = /[A-Z](?=[^A-Z]*$)/g
let p = "Parts spaR";
p.match(reg)
```

Or you can get all the matches and access the last one,

```
let reg = /[A-Z]/g
let r = p.match(reg)
let found = r[r.length-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let tempString=`aaaaaBcCcF`;                   
let result = tempString.split('').filter(value  => {
    let str = '';
    if (value === value.toUpperCase()) {
        str = value;
    }
    return str;
})
console.log(result[result.length-1]);
```

Comment: Your answer were flagged as low-quality one. It's better to give more description about your solution.