# How to find element in array starting from the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider this array:

```
const arr = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4]
,[1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0]
,[undefined, 0, null, 4, 3, null, 0]
,[undefined, undefined, 5, 7, undefined, null, undefined]
];
```

My task is to trim each array. Valid values are integers (or floats, same thing). 0 is also considered valid.
Trimming in this case means that the array needs to be cropped at the beginning and at the end.

In the examples above:

```
arr[0] does not need to remove any element
arr[1] does not need to remove any element
arr[2] needs to remove arr[2][0]
arr[3] needs to remove arr[3][0], arr[3][1] from the beginning and arr[3][4], arr[3][5], arr[3][6] at the end.
```

My approach has been the following:

First find out the first valid element in an array:

```
const foundStartIndex = arr[x].findIndex(el => el >= 0);
```

This will help me to slice the array at the beginning.

But how do I find out from where to start removing at the end?
There is a "lastIndexOf" but it looks it is not accepting a function the same way "findIndex" does.
I could reverse the array, find the first valid element, and calculate where it should be places when it will be reversed back.
But maybe there is a better way to do this?
Please note that I need to know where, at what index, I need to begin to cut as the index will be used for other reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last index of element inside array by certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929260/find-last-index-of-element-inside-array-by-certain-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your approach, I recommend the following:

```
const reverseEndIndex = arr[x].reverse().findIndex(el => el >= 0);
const foundEndIndex = arr[x].length - 1 - reverseLastIndex;
```

The second code line translates the index in the reversed array to the index in the non-reversed array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

I split the problem into 2: trimming the left part and trimming the right part.

To trim the left part, we just go through the array until we get a number, then slice the array from the beginning until that point.

To trim the right, it's just a mirror of the left trim.

Then for good measure, I added in a function that calls the 2 others for ease of use.

Note: Even though I checked for a `number` type, feel free to use a different check, like `Number.isInteger()` or `element >= 0`.

```js
/**
 * @param {Array} arr
 */
function leftTrimArray(arr) {
  let i = 0
  let element = arr[i]
  while (typeof element !== 'number') {
    i++
    element = arr[i]
  }
  return arr.slice(i)
}

/**
 * @param {Array} arr
 */
function rightTrimArray(arr) {
  let i = arr.length - 1
  let element = arr[i]
  while (typeof element !== 'number') {
    i--
    element = arr[i]
  }
  return arr.slice(0, i + 1)
}

function trimArray(arr) {
  return rightTrimArray(leftTrimArray(arr))
}

const arrs = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4],
  [1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0],
  [undefined, 0, null, 4, 3, null, 0],
  [undefined, undefined, 5, 7, undefined, null, undefined]
];

arrs.forEach(arr => {
  console.log(trimArray(arr));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear from your question why you need to use the index "for other reasons", but if you need clean arrays containing only numbers you can `map` over them and then `filter` out everything that isn't `null` or a number.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4],
  [1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 'Bob'],
  [undefined, 0, null, 4, 3, null, 0, 0.2],
  [undefined, undefined, 5, 7, undefined, null, undefined]
];

const out = arr.map(n => n.filter(el => {
  return el !== null && !isNaN(el);
}));

console.log(out);
```