# Targeting text inside the state in array

Tags: javascript

I have this script to target the last game inside an array.

```
const lastMatch = league.data.schedule.events.pop();
```

But that pops the last game, which I understand why. I actually want to target the games that are 'completed'.

I tried

```
const lastMatch = league.data.schedule.events.state('completed');
```

but can't seem to figure it out. [image: Image of league.data.schedule.events]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last matching object in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268863/find-last-matching-object-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the games with the `completed` property by using the `Array#filter` method.

```js
const completed = games.filter(({ state }) => state === "completed")
```

This will return a new array with the elements that meet the specified condition.